# c# custom expression variable (for my lack of a better term)

Tags: c#

What is this called in c#?  And how do you do it/syntax?
Is this called an "inline function"?

I'm in a method.
In this method I want to re-use the same bit of code a few times.  Perhaps as a variable as you can in other languages.

e.g.

```
// I have a bit of code to define an expression expl
line1: int x = 0;
line2: var expl = { x+=2 }
line3: ... use expl // x now =2
line4: ... use expl // x now =4
line5: ... use expl // x now =6
line6: ... ... do other things ...
line7: ... use expl
... and so it goes on
```

Unlike my pseudo-code above, my expression is rather lengthy and I don't fell like I should have to create a function out of it, yet.  In this method is the only place in the application the expression (for my lack of a better term at the moment) will never be used.

Please understand I am not simplistically just trying to add 2 to x in my production expression.  I would do that on each of the lines using `x`. In production `expl` is actually a five line ternary expression (I believe I am using the term expression correctly in this case) so I don't what to just cut-and-past the same five lines over and over :-)

Thanks.

Comment: *“I don't fell like I should have to create a function out of it”* — why?

Comment: Ever hear of a _loop_?

Comment: In this method is the only place in the application the expression.

Comment: MickyD I think someone reading what is happening on the rest of lines 3,4,5, and 7 might understand that a loop is not a reasonable option

Comment: Seemed reasonable to me.  Perhaps your question is unclear?

Comment: FIVE lines expression? With ternary operator? To extract a function (or two or three or five or to introduce more local variables) more often than not is for **clarity, not _just_ for reuse**

Comment: seems like C++ preprocessor macros http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ and they are not supported in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = 0;
Action addTwo = () => x += 2;
addTwo();
addTwo();
```

`Action` is a specific form of `delegate`, which is like an inline function. The fact that it uses a variable declared outside of its own scope makes it a *closure* as well. Other `delegate`s that are defined with the .NET framework include various generic forms of `Action<>` (so you can pass parameters into it), and `Func<>` (so you can return a value from it). But you can also declare your own named delegate that has any method signature you like.

The above code uses a *lambda expression*, or *lambda syntax*, but you can also declare it more explicitly:

```
Action addTwo = delegate() { x += 2 };
```

The yet-to-be-released [C# 7 is expected to have Local Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), which is essentially the same thing, but with slightly different syntax:

```
void AddTwo() => x += 2;
```

or

```
void AddTwo() { x += 2; }
```

Comment: That's great.  My final implementation I when with Func<int> for the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is ["anonymous function" or "lambda expression"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

The easiest way to what you want to do is using the [`Action<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Func<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) generic delegate types. If you want to return a value, use `Func<>`, to return void use `Action<>`.

In your example, you could write the expression line like so:

```
Func<int> expl = () => x += 2;
```

This will add 2 to `x` and return the result.

Comment: You need to give your variable a name.

Comment: @JackA.  I'd like to give both you and StriplingWarrior credit for you answers.  Thanks